# Proof using induction on the length of a formula $\phi$.

Tags: logic, induction, proof-explanation

Working on the book: Derek Goldrei. "*Propositional and Predicate Calculus*"

On p. 19, the principle of induction is stated as follows:

> As before, first prove that $0 \in A$  and then prove that for all $n \in A$,
> if $k \in A$ for all $k \leq n$, then $k \in A$ forall $k \leq n + 1$, to conclude that $A = N$.

On p. 32, prior to proving:

> **Theorem 2.1**
> Any formula $\phi$ contains an equal number of left brackets (and right brackets).

the author explains

> Show first that the result holds for all formulas of length 0 – the basis of the induction. Then we do the inductive step: assume that the result holds for all formulas of the given type with length $\leq n$ – this is the induction hypothesis for $n$ – and from this show that it holds for all formulas of length $\leq n + 1$. As we are assuming that the hypothesis holds for all formulas of length $\leq n$, this boils down to showing that the hypothesis holds for formulas whose length is exactly $n + 1$.

Perhaps, I am missing something but I commonly think as the principle of induction in this way. Proving a property $P$ holds for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, amounts to:

- Show $P(0)$ holds.
- Show $\forall k \in \mathbb{N}(k \geq 0 \land P(k) \to P(k + 1))$

So, my questions are:

- In which way is the definition used by the author related with the common definition of proof by induction ?
- I was used to see $k \geq 0$ and not $k \leq n$. Is this assumption using $\leq$ related in some way to $k \geq 0$?

Answer (score 1):

The definition of the author is logically equivalent to the usual one.

It's just "stronger" in the sense that it makes applying the induction easier. His definition can be quite useful in some cases e.g. if the proof for $N+1$ requires you to know that the statement is true not just for $N$, but also for some smaller values than $N$ (say for $N-1$ and $N-2$).

In that case assuming that the statement is true for all $k \le N$ makes life easier.

I say "stronger" (in quotes) because it's not really stronger, I just said it's logically equivalent. It's just more convenient in some cases.

This proof e.g. with the number of brackets seems to be one such case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Why do you say that, assuming the statement it's true for all $k \leq N$ makes life easier ?